# DotNetOpenId and Asp.net 2.0 or Visual Studio 2005

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2005, .net-2.0, dotnetopenauth

I need to upgrade to 2010 Visual Studio, until then.. it is even possible to use the DOTNETOPENID code with Visual Studio 2005 / Asp.net 2.0 or even VS 2005 .net 3.5?

http://code.google.com/p/dotnetopenid/

I can not load the sample code included with ASP.net 2.0 and Visual Studio 2005.. can anyone help or make suggestion? It seems to require VS2008 or higher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found DotNetOpenID for VS2005 ver 2.5.7.10213